# Secure way to authenticate server processes that need to connect to Oracle

Tags: oracle, authentication, solaris-10

We're using Oracle 11.2, with server processes written in C++ running on Solaris 10.  Our support personnel have their own Oracle user names, and we have a dedicated Oracle user for our server processes (let's call it servuser).

For auditing purposes, we need to make sure that only the server processes use the servuser account to make changes, however, it is also acceptable for support personnel to access the db with servuser, as long as they are doing it from the Solaris box hosting the server processes.

The obvious solution to this would be to use OS authentication - create a Solaris user for the processes, and map it to the Oracle servuser.  The only problem with this: those server processes run on a separate host from the Oracle instance.  Turning on remote authorization is a huge, well-known security hole (just create your own user on your OS - presto).

All the other strategies I can think of are no good:

1. Storing the passwords in files in the Solaris account is no good, as support personnel could see them and use to connect via sqlplus;
2. Encrypting the file would be no good - the server process would have to have access to the private key, which would then be available to the support staff, which could then decrypt & we're back at step 1.
3. I've thought of creating a logon trigger that checks to see if we're connecting as servuser, then raising an exception if the Module/Program values in v$session don't match what we've identified as valid clients.  This is weak protection, as someone could write their own app that would spoof these values.

What is the "official" way of handling this scenario?  OS authentication only works securely if you're running your client on the same box that's hosting your instance, which seems rather useless, IMO.  Yet I would think our scenario is quite common - app servers running on separate instance, but you want to make sure only they can use the privileged account.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best option would generally be to use a [secure external password store](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/SecureExternalPasswordStore_10gR2.php).  This would involve creating a wallet on the server machine that stores the username & password you want to use to connect to Oracle.  If you let the wallet automatically log you in, the server process would not need to have the ability to open the wallet or to see the password and neither would the support personnel.  The wallet can be configured so that automatic logins only work from the server machine making the wallet more or less useless if someone copied it to a different machine.  Of course, someone in the organization would need to have the password for the wallet in case you ever wanted to change the stored password, but there would be no need for that person to be one of the support staff.

Less ideal would be a login trigger that checked the username and the IP address of the client and denied logins if the connections were coming from a machine other than the Solaris box (possibly in addition to checking the module or program).  That generally works but there is always the potential that someone spoofs their IP address.  But spoofing the client IP address and making it look like the app server on the network would generally cause enough routing issues that the attack would be relatively hard to pull off.

Comment: Is the wallet also only applicable to a given os user on a machine?

Comment: @SteveBroberg - You should certainly be able to use Unix file permissions to ensure that only one Solaris user has the ability to access the wallet, yes.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was would someone be able to take that wallet file and use it to be able to log in while being a different os user?  In other words, does it act as a kind of "pass" to get into the db as servuser?  If so, how is that any better than a username/password file?